# Mongo: search sub array

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Looking for users that are a part of a group.

Here is one user:

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.users.find({_id:"rYHRMPpdXRa8fPXrj"})
```

Here is the result the single user:

```
{ "_id" : "rYHRMPpdXRa8fPXrj", "profile" : { "firstName" : "C", "groups" : [ "GJcqFCnSzfvJbuTMS", "gxD85kTiXmbtwaKfo" ]}
```

I try to find...

```
db.users.find({"groups":"rYHRMPpdXRa8fPXrj"})
db.users.find({"profile.groups":"rYHRMPpdXRa8fPXrj"})
db.users.find({profile:{"groups":"rYHRMPpdXRa8fPXrj"}})
db.users.find({"profile":{"groups":"rYHRMPpdXRa8fPXrj"}})
db.users.find({"profile":{"groups":["rYHRMPpdXRa8fPXrj"]}})
db.users.find({profile:{"groups":"rYHRMPpdXRa8fPXrj"}})
db.users.find({profile:{groups:"rYHRMPpdXRa8fPXrj"}})
db.users.find({profile:{groups:["rYHRMPpdXRa8fPXrj"]}})
db.users.find({profile:{$elemMatch:{groups:["rYHRMPpdXRa8fPXrj"]}}})
db.users.find({profile:{$elemMatch:{groups:"rYHRMPpdXRa8fPXrj"}}})
db.users.find({profile:{groups:{$in:["rYHRMPpdXRa8fPXrj"]}}})
```

I get nothing. ARRRG!!

How do I find all users in a specific profile.group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing your user _id into your query instead of the group id(?).

Try:

```
db.users.find({"profile.groups":"GJcqFCnSzfvJbuTMS"})
```

for example

Comment: Doh! Thanks, Wake. Also, it's great to know the syntax for nested data points, like "profile.groups". Awesome. It worked.

Answer (score -2):

$all should be used to filter by items within array:

```
db.users.find({profile:{groups:{$all:["rYHRMPpdXRa8fPXrj"]}}})
```